# get the values a of property with name stored in a string

Tags: c#

I have two Combo Boxes with values up to 70 and 15, and I have a class containing data properties for each Combo Box item. Now to write if-statement or switch-statement for each of these values will amount to ...TOO MUCH WORK. So, I need to loop through the Combo Box items and extract the item I need which I now will, as a variable, use to call the corresponding property, retrieving its data/values.

One point though, these properties returns strings of double indexer eg. string[,] . For more clarification, let me demonstrate this...

```
 public class myClass
 {
    public string[,] myProperty                
    {
     get { return myData;}
    }
 }
```

there are 70 such properties, each for corresponding combo box item

```
public class mainClass
{
    string[,] myData=null;
}
```

Here is where I need to call myProperty through the instance of my class, retrieving all the data it contains and writing it into myData. Bearing in mind the above condition, concerning the Combo Boxes.
Do you have a hint

Answer (score 1):

to do this you will have to use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

so

```
typeof(myClass).GetProperty("propertyName").GetValue(obj);
```

and you will have the value retrived even if you have property names in strings

Comment: what does the object (obj) represent?

Comment: it represents the object which has the property named "propertyName"

Comment: Thanks, but one more thing, I have the property value as string[,]; can you advice on how to retrieve all its value as string[,]. How to convert the value.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks Parv...string[,] strCheck = (string[,])typeof(myClass).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(instaceOfmyClass, null);